# Google Map layer refresh with Geojson

Tags: google-maps, geojson

I am able to plot data onto google maps using geojson. I now want to refresh the markers every 10 seconds. How can I do this? In my example below the json file would refresh on my local server. How can I change the properties/ position of the same marker?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  html, body, #map {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var map;
var layer1;
var layer2;
function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
                        zoom: 11,
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.0171240, 72.5330533),
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                     };


    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
layer1 = map.data.loadGeoJson('http://localhost/envitia.its.webclient/myjson.json');

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use the `setInterval()` function in javascript? In you initialize() function, just wrap the layer1 command in a setInterval() with a time of 10 seconds.

Comment: Thanks that works but leaves the old markers on the map. I want to completely reload the layer so that the old markers are removed.

Comment: Put the markers into an array. Then clear the markers from the array before adding the new markers. There are samples on Google's API Doc site.

Comment: But how do I have the list of markers when I am using loadGeoJson function? Could you please give me the link of the Google API Doc site example?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question and the comment from Todd is correct. Per the Google Maps API, the GeoJSON functions just load a bunch of features in into the map. To remove them, you can either

1. Remove every feature and start over
2. Implement some logic to remove only the features that need to be removed and selectively add ones not already on the map

It varies slightly if you use the .addGeoJson() function vs .loadGeoJson(). If you use the first one, you can do something like

```
        if (mapFeatures != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < mapFeatures.length; i++) {
                map.data.remove(mapFeatures[i]);
            }
        }
        geoJSON = jQuery.parseJSON(json.data);
        mapFeatures=map.data.addGeoJson(geoJSON);
```

mapFeatures is an array of Data.Feature objects which are just iterated and removed. If you use the .loadGeoJson() method instead, then you can use the forEach() method to iterate though the collection in the map object.

Have a look at the API reference. There is also a contains() method if you want to implement selective feature removal
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data